# Is there a way to make the faster ordered SQL TOP 1 query as Entity Framework query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here is two ways to get the top 1 row from a table ordered

Slower:

```
select top 1 * 
from movies m
where m.Distributor = 'any'
order by m.IMDB_Rating desc
```

Faster:

```
select top 1 m.* 
from movies m
left join movies m2 on m.Distributor = m2.Distributor 
                    and m2.IMDB_Rating > m.IMDB_Rating
where m.Distributor = 'any' 
  and m.IMDB_Rating is not null 
  and m2.id is null
```

The first one is simpler, but the second one is faster.

So, is there a way to make the second query using Entity Framework?

If there is no way to make this query in EF or EF Core, could you give me another query as fast as the second one if it is possible?

I'm sorry if it is duplicated, I can't find any answer to my question

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select top (1) m.*
from movies m
where m.Distributor = 'any'
order by m.IMDB_Rating desc;
```

You want an index on `movies(Distributor, IMDB_Rating desc)`.

I cannot speak to why the second version would be faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm avoiding creating a new index, only if it is the only way to solve my problem.

For 1048576 rows in my table, see the execution plan of the two queries: [Execution plan](https://i.ibb.co/280xt64/1-Execution-plan.png).

Comment: That execution plan should be in the question, it is pretty vital to understanding your pattern.

Comment: Adding an index to the DB really is the best approach here, OPs second query is similar to finding the Max IMDB rating for a Distributor and then finding the movie that matches that rating value, which is complicated logic to get around the fact that the database is not optimised for this type of query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your answer perfectly.

I understand that if I create an index in my first query, it'll be as fast as the second one. But I really don't want to do it only if there is no other way to solve my problem.

For me, create an index is a good solution, but not if I can do that without it, otherwise, my database will be full of index and I really wouldn't want it to be like that.

I can explain why, but in summary it is because of performance of my system, so I'm accepting more complexity in this case.

Thanks a lot for you take your time to answer me.